# Set WM_CLASS (with wnck, xprop, or something else)

Tags: python, launcher, wnck

I'm trying to group multiple Chrome standalone windows under the same launcher in Ubuntu 14.04. It doesn't seem to be possible simply to specify multiple `WM_CLASS` variables in the .desktop file (see comments on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/294350/66309)).

The first solution I hit on is to use xprop to change the WM_CLASS of the extra windows to be the same as a chosen master window, after a short delay. This works if I don't specify which window to change at the command line, let it give me a crosshair, and click on the wayward window, with a command like this:

```
xprop -f WM_CLASS 8s -set WM_CLASS crx_kphgejagakmceapfinpoopapfdnkkepf
```

(taken without much understanding from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/750134/66309) answer to the same question)

It gets the new `WM_CLASS`, and Ubuntu immediately regroups it under the chosen launcher rather than Chrome.

However, despite the window to all appearances having the very simple name `Todoist` (this is what appears on the title bar, and `xprop | grep -i name` gives

```
WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Todoist"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Todoist"
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

So, I decide xprop can't be trusted.

Instead, I found I can use the python package wnck to access this window, after a fashion:

```
import wnck
todoist = [w for w in wnck.screen.get_defaults().get_windows()
           if 'todoist' in w.get_name().lower()][0]
```

So, how can I use this object `todoist` to change the underlying `WM_CLASS`?

I realize this is totally an xy-problem question, and so am open to completely different approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WM_CLASS` is [a tuple of name and class](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/wm-class.html) and `xprop` can't set properties which take multiple values (or rather, it can only set the first value). I didn't find any tool that could do it and ended up writing [this small c script](https://gist.github.com/tgr/eae411cefde08cbed5c59d4f51ddb062) in the end. You could probably translate it into Python using [python-xlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xlib) if you prefer that (I normally would but was deterred by the total lack of documentation).

Comment: I eventually solved a similar problem, though with Firefox, using xprop and [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1118101/use-multiple-firefox-wm-classes-in-same-profile). Your script does seem to change the second segment if I pass the window class as something like `0x5800001`, so I'll mark it as the answer, and maybe make use of it later; thanks.

Comment: Also, for posterity, I compiled it as `gcc set_wm_class.c -lX11 -o set_wm_class`.

Answer (score 4):

Fmstrat@github [pointed out](https://gist.github.com/tgr/eae411cefde08cbed5c59d4f51ddb062#gistcomment-3524445) that [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) ([man](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)) can do it:

```
apt install -y xdotool
xdotool search --name "Title of App" set_window --class "New WM Class"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer while struggling with Microsoft Teams window name.

I use the window class to display a list of window on my desktop and I use the right part of the class to get the app name such as:

```
 0x0320002c  0 Navigator.Firefox     LSA-XPS-13-9310 Messages pour le Web - Mozilla Firefox
```

will display "Firefox"

However teams is using a space in the classname:

```
0x04800005  0 microsoft teams - preview.Microsoft Teams - Preview  LSA-XPS-13-9310 Microsoft Teams
```

So my taskbar didn't display the name at all.

I used:

```
xdotool search --name "Teams" set_window --class "Microsoft"
xdotool search --name "Teams" set_window --classname "Teams"
```

to modify both the right and left part of the class, which is displayed as this by xprop :  `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Microsoft", "Teams"`, [and thus my taskbar now works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spzRL.png).