# Do not group specific Xorg applications of the same type

Tags: window, grouping, gnome

I have a few instances (windows) of the same program. Of course, Gnome will group them and handle them as multiple windows of the same application. Grouping affects the task panel that I use, but also things like icons and Alt+Tab.

Not that rarely, it may happen that I have two windows of the same application that should not be treated as two instances of the same, but as fundamentally different. So I do not want to group them. This may affect the following applications in practice:

- Eclipse (If I have multiple different Eclipse installations)
- Many Java applications
- Same for C# applications due to Mono
- Running chromium as standalone with `--app`
- ...

I do not care how this may be achieved and I am willing to put greater amounts of effort to achieve this goal since it is a major annoyance on a daily basis. I am using Gnome with the Dash-To-Panel addon, solutions may be specific to that setup or more broad.

---

What I tried so far: I tried manipulating the `WM_CLASS` property of the windows, but it does not really work because the property seems more to be used to *group* windows, not to *un*group them. Furthermore, the WM does not really always respect the `StartupWMClass` property in desktop files and the `xprop` command is not that useful.

Comment: Warning: When writing this question, I had fundamentally wrong assumptions about how the `StartupWMClass` works. Setting it won't change the WM class of the application. It is only to tell the window manager how to associate a window to its desktop file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a hacky workaround to resolve this problem.

> the property seems more to be used to group windows, not to ungroup them.

This was a false assumtion. The truth is that the `WM_CLASS` is a tuple consisting of a `res_name` and a `res_class` ([RTFM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/wm-class.html)). The latter one is usually referred to as the `WM_CLASS` and is also the one you change normally.

So I extended the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396190/6094756) to a very similar question to change the `res_name` as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long value;
    char *terminatedAt;
    XClassHint class;
    Status status;
    Display *display;
    Window window;

    if ( argc != 4 ) {
        printf( "Usage: %s <window id> <window class> <application name>\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }
    window = strtoul( argv[1], &terminatedAt, 0 );
    if ( *terminatedAt != '\0' ) {
        printf( "Could not parse window id: %s\n", argv[1] );
        return 2;
    }

    display = XOpenDisplay( NULL );
    status = XGetClassHint( display, window, &class );
    if ( !status ) return 4;

    XFree( class.res_class );
    XFree( class.res_name );
    class.res_class = strdup( argv[2] );
    class.res_name = strdup( argv[3] );
    printf("Setting WM_CLASS of window %lu to res_name=\"%s\", res_class=\"%s\"\n", window, class.res_name, class.res_class );
    XSetClassHint( display, window, &class );

    XCloseDisplay( display );
    XFree( class.res_name );
    XFree( class.res_class );
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc set_wm_class.c -lX11 -o set_wm_class`and use `xdotool getactivewindow` to get the required WID.

---

By the way I am open to less hacky solutions. I will award a bounty of 100 reputation for a way to set the full `WM_CLASS` using `xprop -set` and thus making this script obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You can now 'disable' the alt-tab grouping in Gnome. In your Gnome keybindings, change the keybinding from 'Switch applications' to 'Switch windows'.

https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/2018/10/11/the-future-of-alternatetab-and-why-you-need-not-worry/